# PG-1130 11 speed cassette hub compatibility

Tags: cassette, freehub

I am building a rear wheel and I have a PG-1130 Sram Cassette(11-42T). On the specifications they say:

*11-42t cassette fits 10 and 11-speed non-XD™ driver bodies (1.85mm spacer is required for 11-speed drivers*

Does this mean I can buy a 10-Speed rear hub? More specifically, I am looking for a 135MM, QR with Disc rear hub(36H). Do you guys have any suggestions? I'm looking for a reasonably priced one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a roundabout way of saying that it fits on a Shimano style HG hub. I guess SRAM don’t like using the word Shimano. The NX groupset was designed as a good budget retrofit onto the most common freehub.

Yes you can use any (10 speed) rear wheel with a Shimano HG hub.

Recommendations are out of scope for this site sorry but any online store or even better your local bike store can help.